# convert Golang regex to JS regex

Tags: javascript, regex, go

I have a regex from Golang (nameComponentRegexp). How can I convert it to JavaScript style regex?

The main blocking problem for me:

1. How can I do `optional` and `repeated` in JavaScript correctly
2. I tried copy from `` match(`(?:[._]|__|[-]*)`) `` but it cannot match single period or single underscore. I tried it from online regex tester.

The description from Golang:

> nameComponentRegexp restricts registry path component names to start
>       with at least one letter or number, with following parts able to be
>       separated by one period, one or two underscore and multiple dashes.

```
alphaNumericRegexp = match(`[a-z0-9]+`)
separatorRegexp = match(`(?:[._]|__|[-]*)`)

nameComponentRegexp = expression(
    alphaNumericRegexp,
    optional(repeated(separatorRegexp, alphaNumericRegexp)))
```

Some valid example:

- a.a
- a_a
- a__a
- a-a
- a--a
- a---a

Comment: Show your best attempt.

Comment: Repeating and/or optional groups or characters are a standard [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) feature that is regex 101. So maybe something like `/^[a-z\d]+((?:[._]|__|[-]*)[a-z\d]+)*$/`

Comment: I presume `repeated()` means "all" so is normally implemented as the `g` flag in other languages. What does `optional()` do? Does it return an option monad?

Comment: @slebetman https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/reference/regexp.go#L120

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See how you build the `nameComponentRegexp`: you start with `alphaNumericRegexp` and then match 1 or 0 occurrences of 1 or more sequences of `separatorRegexp`+`alphaNumericRegexp`.

[`optional()`](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/reference/regexp.go#L118) does the following:

> // optional wraps the expression in a non-capturing group and makes the
>   // production optional.
>
> ```
> func optional(res ...*regexp.Regexp) *regexp.Regexp {
>   return match(group(expression(res...)).String() + `?`)
> }
> ```

[`repeated()`](https://github.com/docker/distribution/blob/master/reference/regexp.go#L118) does this:

> // repeated wraps the regexp in a non-capturing group to get one or more
>   // matches.
>
> ```
> func repeated(res ...*regexp.Regexp) *regexp.Regexp {
>   return match(group(expression(res...)).String() + `+`)
> }
> ```

Thus, what you need is

```
/^[a-z0-9]+(?:(?:[._]|__|-*)[a-z0-9]+)*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cm1qY3/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-z0-9]+` - 1 or more alphanumeric symbols
- `(?:(?:[._]|__|-*)[a-z0-9]+)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `(?:[._]|__|-*)` - a `.`, `_`, `__`, or 0+ hyphens
  - `[a-z0-9]+`- 1 or more alphanumeric symbols

If you want to disallow strings like `aaaa`, you need to replace all `*` in the pattern (2 occurrences) with `+` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/Bcmdjb/1)).

JS demo:

```js
var ss = ['a.a','a_a','a__a','a-a','a--a','a---a'];
var rx = /^[a-z0-9]+(?:(?:[._]|__|-*)[a-z0-9]+)*$/;
for (var s of ss) {
 console.log(s,"=>", rx.test(s));
}
```